# Create multi-page website with one org-mode file

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

When exporting an org file to html, it appears that one org file translates to one html file. Is it possible to have certain headings export as a separate file, so that we end up with a main page and a number of sub-pages, all from one org file? For example, the [Org Guide](http://orgmode.org/guide/index.html) looks like it could logically be laid out in a single file.

Comment: The Org Guide seems to be like a table of contents for different org files. I understand that this is not what you are looking for but org-mode's [sitemaps](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html#sec-8-1) might be helpful.

Comment: `ox-hugo` provides something with this motivation. I do still like to know if there are other alternatives .

Comment: @trblnc Thanks for suggesting`ox-hugo` :) May I ask what features you are looking for in alternatives?

Comment: Maybe we can continue on the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168517/create-multi-page-website-with-one-org-mode-file).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.  But, no, the current (8.0.x) HTML exporter does not have a capability to generate multiple files.

One way to do it is to generate a texi file with the texinfo exporter, then convert the texi file to html with `makeinfo --html`.  As the Org Guide seems to be generated by this way.

Answer (score 4):

If you are still looking for a solution (after 5 years), and you are open to using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) for static site generation, [`ox-hugo`](https://ox-hugo.scripter.co) is an option.

`ox-hugo` is an Org exporter backend that exports Org files to Hugo-compatible Markdown files with front-matter. The content can be organized so that you can export the Org subtrees as separate content files, or just have one Org file for each exported file, or you can have a mix of that.

If you look at the above linked `ox-hugo` site, it is generated from a single Org file; you will find the Org source linked in the footer of that site.

*Disclaimer: I am the `ox-hugo` author.*

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun my-org-export-each-level-1-headline-to-html (&optional scope)
(interactive)
 (org-map-entries
  (lambda ()
    (let* ((title (car (last (org-get-outline-path t))))
           (dir (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))
           (filename (concat dir title ".html")))
  (org-narrow-to-subtree)
      (org-html-export-as-html)
        (write-file filename)
        (kill-current-buffer)
  (widen)))
  "LEVEL=1" scope))
```

It generates html file for each headline level=1. Based on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54937/split-every-single-org-headline-in-a-org-file-to-separate-md-org-files